# Mongoose $or condition to either match one object, or another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get mongoose to return me models that match ALL of the fields of either the first object, or the second.

This is my code:

```
query.$or = [
    // Either we need a nice meet with attendees
    {
        attendees: {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: []
        }
    },

    // Or we need a nice event with images
    {
        facebookId: {
            $exists: true
        },
        images: {
            $exists: true,
            $ne: []
        }
    }
];
```

It is strange because if I try getting events with only the ATTENDEES field it won't work with this code, but it will work if I do it like this without the $or condition:

```
query.attendees = {
    $exists: true,
    $ne: []
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample documents?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a problem with Mockgoose. Buggy library. Not using it any more.